# Will jqueryUI Drag & Drop work with a tablet?

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-ui

If I use the jQueryUI Drag & Drop plugin will it work as expected on a tablet?

I'm worried if a tablet would think the user was trying to scroll the page instead of dragging an item.

I don't have a tablet to test with so I was wondering if anyone knows if this an issue or not and if so is there any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but you'll need to use http://www.gotproject.com/blog/post2.html

Answer (score 10):

Gotproject gave me problems when I tried making a jQueryUI .dialog() draggable with it.

I had better results with the jQueryUI TouchPunch library:

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

That allowed me to make the my dialog draggable and resizeable using the standard jQueryUI methods, like so:

```
$("#divSingleNamePicker").parent().draggable().resizeable();
```

(NB: the .parent() is in there because jqueryUI .dialog() wraps your target div with a div of its own.)

**Correction 25/10/2012**

I was wrong about having to add the .draggable().resizeable() line to the jQuery.Dialog().  Just loading up the touch-punch library was enough to make it draggable and resizeable automatically.